# Deploy Laravel in HostGator Shared Hosting not in root domain

Tags: laravel-5

I came across a project where I have to deploy a Laravel app in a domain that is not the root domain of a HostGator shared business hosting account, but one of the added domains. Anyone has any experience with this type of deployment?

Thank you in advance.